# how to convert svg to png image in internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, svg, highcharts

i have a chart that created with highchart.
i need to save svg to png in internet Explorer.
i use from follow code and exist security Error in ie11.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgChart = document.createElement('img');
imgChart.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg))));
imgChart.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(imgChart, 0, 0);
    var blobObject = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, 'save.png');
})
```

Comment: So what's not working? What do you mean `and exist security Error` ?

Comment: ctx.drawImage(imgChart, 0, 0); not working in ie

Comment: Well it should: it's supported since IE9 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975414(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: btoa not working in ie?

Comment: btoa is also supported since IE9. What's the error in the console?

Comment: It's a known security restriction in IE. Only workaround: use canvas methods to reproduce the svg. A library like canvg does this for you.

Comment: canvas methods??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I didn't found an satisfying dupe target, so I'll rewrite it as an answer :*

---

**Drawing an SVG image through `drawImage` method will taint the canvas in IE < Edge for security reasons.**

This operation is somehow sensitive for browsers, since svg images imply to parse some XML, and that it can contain some tricky elements <sub>(though IE doesn't support `<foreignObject>`...)</sub>
So quite often, browsers will add security restrictions when SVG images are drawn to it, and will block all exporting methods.

This is the case in safari > 9 when an `<foreignObject>` is drawn on it, this was also the case in chrome, but only when the image comes from an Blob <sub>(an [implementation bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675608), but they finally leveraged the security restriction altogether anyway).</sub>
And then in IE < Edge, with any SVG.

The only way to workaround this issue is to parse yourself the SVG, and then use [the canvas' methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) to reproduce it.

This is all doable, but can take some time to implement, so even though I don't really like it, you'd probably be better using an library like [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg), which does exactly this (parsing + rendering with canvas methods).

Comment: is possible to use Canvg in angular4 projects?

Comment: @anand dunno... But I don't see why not.

Comment: facing difficult to install canvg package

Comment: @anand well you could always try to write it yourself, but I am sorry, I don't know angularjs at all, but I don't see why it wouldn't be able to run the basic js canvg is using.

Comment: now am trying to implement the workaround in javascript. can you share the code?

Comment: @3zzy what "code"? Of the thing that "take some time to implement"? Nope. Of how to use a library? They've got readmes.

Comment: @Kaiido Just pseudo code or a list of steps for the the thing that 'takes time time to implement' ? I'll give it a shot and if it works, share it here.