# Image failed to load in Canvas in IE

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, base64

Not able to load image in canvas to get encode Base64 code

Code

```
var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("d3"));
var img = document.getElementById("img") as HTMLImageElement
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(html.toString())

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); --> showing SecurityError

var data =  dataURL.replace("data:image/svg+xml;base64", "");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: ERROR Error: SecurityError  & ERROR CONTEXT [object Object] in console

Comment: my IE version is 11.9

Comment: Yes IE below Edge did taint the canvas whenever an svg image was drawn on it. For simple svg images you can use canvas methods to reproduce it though, canvg library does just that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert svg to png image in internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225871/how-to-convert-svg-to-png-image-in-internet-explorer)